# How to crawl websites without getting blocked?

Tags: selenium, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I crawl websites very often at the rate of hundreds of requests in an hour.

1. How to make crawlers behavior more like a human?
2. How to not get on radar by detection bots?

Currently crawling site with selenium, chrome.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: You are asking us to help you avoid detection on sites that clearly don't want your bot there. Why would we do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you will have to pause the script between loops.

```
import time
time.sleep(1)
time.sleep(N)
```

So, it could hypothetically work like this.

```
import json,urllib.request
import requests
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase
import time

alldata = []
for c in ascii_lowercase:
    response = requests.get('https://reservia.viarail.ca/GetStations.aspx?q=' + c)
    json_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') 
    df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(json_data), columns=['sc', 'sn', 'pv'])  # etc., 
    time.sleep(3)
    alldata.append(df)
```

Or, look for an API to grab data from the URL you are targeting.  You didn't post an actual URL, so it's impossible to say for sure if an API is exposed or not.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways that sites can detect you are trying to crawl them.  The easiest is probably IP.  If you are making requests too fast from the same IP you might get blocked.  You can introduce (random) delays into your script to try and appear slower.

To continue going fast as possible, you will have to use different IP addresses.  There are many proxy and VPN services that you can use to accomplish this.

Comment: it's trivial to detect if a request was made from WebDriver, regardless of the IP it originates from.

Comment: How is that?  Does it add some headers?